# playwright metadata for a test suite

Tags: ui-automation, playwright

I am trying to add some custom metadata information in my tests like below

```
test.describe('my test suite',()=>{
    test('my first p0 test',()=>{}).meta({
      priority:0,
      
    });
    test('my first p0 test',() = {}).meta({ priority:1});
}).meta({
  owningTeam: 'business-ux'
});
```

and use the metadata to target set of test to run.
Can you please help me with what support we have for such requirements in playwright?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine playwright with allure.

installing it with

```
npm i -D @playwright/test allure-playwright
```

or you can add it into playwright.config.ts:

```
{
  reporter: "allure-playwright";
}
```

see more on https://www.npmjs.com/package/allure-playwright

And also you can add test.steps and priority and test name and description and lot more meta data that it supported by allure.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up following this pattern to capture additional metadata.

```
interface ITestMetadata {
  priority: number;
  owner: string;
}

const testWrapper = (metadata: ITestMetadata) => {
  console.log(
    `Test owner ${metadata.owner}, test Priority ${metadata.priority}`
  );
  return base.extend({});
};
// ----- and in test file --- 
const test = testWrapper({
  owner: "playwright",
  priority: 0,
});

test.describe("Capture additional metadata", () => {
  test("metadata being captured", () => {
    expect(1).toBe(1);
  });
});
```